# Algorithm to calculate 5 interval points from 1 to n

Tags: algorithm, math, intervals

If I have a given series of numbers that count up by 1, say 1-10 or 1-20 or 1-100 etc. And I want to calculate 5 or 6 evenly spaced points from the beginning to the end of that series, including the beginning and end as one point each, is there a math algorithm I can use to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Division not working or available on your platform? Sounds like you are missing a crucial piece of info in your question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Division working on my platform? Of course it is.

Comment: So what is the problem? 100/5 = 20, thus interval is 20. What you fail to mention if you only need integers or if any number type will do.

Comment: Sorry. I am not a top programmer, so I may not be thinking of all the things I need to. But yes, I need integers only.

Comment: Let's use a simple example: 1-10 and 5 intervals. Seems like span-width is 2 (10/5), but 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 does not match start and end. So what to do in these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the start and end of your range of numbers, call them `start` and `end`.  If they were from 1-100, for example, `start` would 1, `end` would be 100.

Now take the number of evenly spaced points you want.  Take one off it, and call the result `N`.  So if you wanted 5 points, `N` will be 4.

Now we can make a formula, for how far apart the points should be.  Take `end`, subtract `start`, add 1, and divide the result by `N`.  So:

```
width = (end - start + 1) / N
```

For our example, `(100 - 1 + 1) / 4 = 25`.  To find the evenly-spaced points themselves, start with `start`.  From one point, to get the next add `width`.  So here, `start` is 1, and it is our first point.  The next is is `1 + 25 = 26`.  Then `26 + 25 = 51`, etc.  Stop once you pass `end`, and use `end` instead.  So instead of `76 + 25 = 101`, just use `100`.

The last number doesn't land perfectly on `100`, and generally it won't unless you choose `start`, `end` and `N` carefully.  But it will be close.